# Accessing Array of Array Elements in Angular 2

Tags: angular, arrayofarrays

I have an array of array and want to all access the elements of it using *ngFor one by one [Example Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD5JZ.png)

If some help can be given, I can access the main array but not the elements of array within an array.

My output should be:
MS, Data1, Date2, name, 20 , pink

I am trying to do

```
  <li *ngFor="let l of carels">
    <input
      type="text"
      class="col-sm-6"
      value="{{l.name}}">

    <input
      type="text"
      class="col-sm-3"
      value="{{l.category}}">

    <input
      type="date"
      class="col-sm-3"
      value="{{l.date}}">

  </li>
```

But cannot access the elements of inner array

My inner array is of type :

```
export class SharedPeople {
constructor(public nameIn: string, public age: number) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You nedd an other ngFor to loop through the names

```
<li *ngFor="let l of carels">
    <div *ngFor="let name of l.names">{{ name.nameln + ": " + name.age}} </div>

    <input      type="text"      class="col-sm-3"      value="{{l.category}}">
    <input      type="date"      class="col-sm-3"      value="{{l.date}}">
  </li>
```

Comment: sorry for asking a question in comment box, bcoz i am ban to ask question on this plateform. how can i access this array variables `[Array(2)] 0: Array(2) 0: {id: 5, name: "Eternis", …} 1: {id: 4, name: "Sprenza", …} length: 2 __proto__: Array(0) length: 1 __proto__: Array(0). i am trying this way *ngFor="let item of bookedItems" `. but i failed any suggestion?